# ionic A problem occurred starting process prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\mips64el-linux-android-strip

Tags: node.js, google-maps, cordova, ionic-framework

I create a new ionic app with

```
> ionic start myAppNameHere blank
```

And I add google maps for android and ios to my app following this [link: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native-google-maps/blob/master/documents/README.md](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native-google-maps/blob/master/documents/README.md). I also run the following command

```
> ionic cordova platform add android && ionic cordova build android
```

But I get this error:

> Execution failed for task ':app:transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbolForDebug'.
>
> A problem occurred starting process 'command 'C:\Users\myusernamehere\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\toolchains\mips64el-linux-android-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\mips64el-linux-android-strip'' `

Someone can help me please

Answer (score 0):

Below is a summation of my experience installing [cordova](/questions/tagged/cordova) on [ionic](/questions/tagged/ionic). See in particular the section on [mips64el-linux-android](/questions/tagged/mips64el-linux-android) error. Just follow along and create the dummy folder and subfolders as explained.

Cordova expects to see the path to ***`C:\Users\myusernamehere\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\toolchains\mips64el-linux-android-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\mips64el-linux-android-strip`*** but does not require it (in my case) and will throw an error if absent.

**Ionic Cordova Installation experience.**

```
• Re- install Java JDK 8 to the latest update.
• Add ANDROID_SDK_ROOT variable to point to existing installation of Android Studio SDK
• Add Java JDK\bin to the environment PATH variable on user and system
• Download Gradle 5.2 and create folder C:\Gradle and extract the contents inside. Your 
The path should look like this
```

> `C:\Gradle\gradle-5.2\bin\gradle.bat`

- Add `"C:\Gradle\gradle-5.2\bin"` to PATH variable on System

  From the command line do the following ..

> 1. `export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk`
> 2. `export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools/bin`
> 3. `export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platform-tools`
> 4. `export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/emulator`

```
• Using a previously installed edition of Android Studio go to Tools => SDK Tools 
And check the NDK checkbox for download, click apply and ok.
• In the project terminal - Enter
```

> ionic cordova prepare android

to build Cordova.
    If there are errors delete the `platforms\android` project directory and rebuild.
If there is a Gradle error looking for NDK `"mips64el-linux-android-version"`

```
Do the following ..  

• Open the NDK bundle\toolchains folder within Android SDK eg C:\Users\Shay\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\toolchains
• And using command line create a folder "mips64el-linux-android-4.9" ( same version number (4.9) as other folders) inside create folder "prebuilt" .. then folder "windows-x86_64" and inside place and empty text file for contents. 
The created path should look like .. "C:\Users\Shay\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\toolchains\mips64el-linux-android-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\dummy file"  is not required by Cordova but is expected to be in its path .. otherwise it will throw an error and fail to build.
```

*Alternatively, download an older build such as https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/older_releases/android-ndk-r16b-windows-x86_64.zip and extract the required folder to the new [ndk](/questions/tagged/ndk) folder in the same location as above.*

```
• Finally, once again enter
```

> ionic cordova prepare android

to build Cordova

```
The Ionic build order (as I observed it) is a follows ..

1. It looks for all the relevant Java and Android SDK paths .. 
2. Then uses Gradle as the build system .. 
3. Check for NDK bundle ..
4. Build project
```

The above took me two days to figure out. Hope it helps and saves you the headache.